# Problema com o classificador em PLN

Tags: python, inteligência-artificial

Estou desenvolvendo um chatbot, e para buscar a resposta estou usando o classificador de Naive Bayes realizando a classificação das perguntas e respostas. Para quem quiser ver todo o código do projeto e mais definições segue o link do [GitHub](https://github.com/ZehLuckmann/Roger)

Para desenvolver estou usando a biblioteca TextBlob para python, o problema é que ao treinar o meu classificador ele esta retornando sempre a mesma mensagem, idependente da entrada que eu uso. A mensagem é:

> "Tudo bom?"

Ainda não consegui identificar o problema, não sei se o problema esta na forma em que meus dados estão dispostos para realizar o treino o se é na forma em que estou treinando p classificador.

Minha classe que realiza o processo de classificação é esta:

```
#encoding: utf-8
#!/usr/bin/env python
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
from textblob import TextBlob
import logging

class Talk(object):
    """A classe Talk é responsável por retornar a resposta
    de uma frase, baseando nas informações exportadas. Utilizando a classificação
    de acordo com o teorema de Bayes
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Construtor da classe

        cl -> Armazena o classificador
        accuracy -> Armazena a precisão do algoritmo
        """
        self.__cl = None
        self.__accuracy = 0


    def train(self, train_set):
        """
        Treina com a lista de informações formada de frases e suas
        respectivas classificações:
        """

        logging.debug('Inicia treinamento da previsão de intenção')
        self.__cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(train_set)
        logging.debug('Treinamento da previsão de intenção finalizado')

    def test(self, test_set):
        """
        Realiza testes com a lista de informações formada
        de frases e sua respectiva classificação para obter a precisão:
        """

        logging.debug('Inicia teste da previsão de intenção')
        self.__accuracy = self.__cl.accuracy(test_set)
        logging.debug('Teste da previsão de intenção finalizado')
        logging.info('Precisão da previsão: {}'.format(self.__accuracy))

    def response(self, phrase):
        """
        Retorna a rasposta da frase de acordo com o classificador criado
        """
        logging.debug('Analisa a frase "{}"'.format(phrase))
        blob = TextBlob(phrase,classifier=self.__cl)
        result = blob.classify()
        logging.debug('Resposta: "{}"'.format(result))
        return result
```

Segue o link do meu arquivo com as informações de treino e dos dados de teste

- [Treino](https://github.com/ZehLuckmann/Roger/blob/master/src/roger/database/dados_treino_ze.csv)
- [Teste](https://github.com/ZehLuckmann/Roger/blob/master/src/roger/database/dados_teste_ze.csv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de muitos testes, consegui descobir qual era o problema.

O problema era a quantidade de classes possíveis que o classificador precisava interpretar

Por exemplo o seguinte conjunto de treino:

```
oie, oi
oi, oiee
olá, oii
tudo bem?, tudo certo
td bem?, tudo bom
tudo bom?, tudo tranquilo
```

No caso acima, todas as respostas são diferentes entre si, por mais que seja óbvio que existem respostas com o mesmo significado o classificador não consegue fazer esta análise. Resumindo no exemplo acima eu tenho **6 entradas e 6 classes** de saída, isso é péssimo para um classificador apreender qualquer coisa.

Minha solução foi definir classes de resposta:

```
oie, [oi]
oi, [oi]
olá, [oi]
tudo bem?, [resposta tudo bem]
td bem?, [resposta tudo bem]
tudo bom?, [resposta tudo bem]
```

Agora eu tenho uma situação completamente diferente, eu tenho **6 entradas e 2 classes** de saída, e isso faz com que a precisão nas respostas subisse absurdamente.